# search and delete duplicate entries inside a file for a line

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ansible

I have an file with the below content

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -G dockerroot -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-snapshots-dev.cto.com'
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker
```

There are duplicate entries for `--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com` and `--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com`  i need to keep only one occurrence of above entries.

file should look like this

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -G dockerroot -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-snapshots-dev.cto.com'
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker
```

Entries can be in any order.

Comment: will all the `--insecure etc` entries be always be next to each other? and what have you tried, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev\.cto\.com//2g;s/--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev\.cto\.com//2g' file
```

It deletes both strings from second occurrence.

**Output:**

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -G dockerroot -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com   --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-snapshots-dev.cto.com  '
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my perl based solution:

```
perl -pe 'for my $s ("--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com","--insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com") {if (($a,$b)=/^(.*?$s)(.+)$/s) {$b=~s/$s //g; $_="$a$b"}}' input.txt
```

The idea is that we process each line separately. We split it into 2 parts: the first part contains everything up to and including the string to be removed (e.g. `-insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com`). The second part contains everything else. Then we remove all occurrences of the string from the second part. Finally we concatenate the 2 parts and we output that.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: `--insecure` entries are grouped together towards end of line

Main logic is that initial portion is separated out, `--insecure` entries are put in an array and then unique is printed out

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -ne "if(/--insecure/){(@b)=/^(.*?)(?=--insecure.*)/; (@a)=/--insecure.*?(?= --|')/g; print \"@b\"; print join(' ',uniq(@a)); print \"'\n\"} else {print}" ip.txt
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -G dockerroot -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-releases-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-stable-dev.cto.com --insecure-registry my-demo-auto-images-snapshots-dev.cto.com'
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker
```